# A baffling and silly LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, linker

Here is the first file

```
extern void init();

int main()
{
    init();
}
```

And now for the second and last file

```
inline void init()
{
  return;
}
```

These 2 C++ files were built under Visual Studio 2015 as a Win32 console application project. The .pdb files were generated after their compilation.
So why is it the linker cannot resolve external function `init()`?

> test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: Your suggestion works like a charm !  I don't know how to thank you Mr. Burr, It is as if you almost saved my life.

Answer (score 2):

From C++11 3.2/3 "One definition rule":

> An inline function shall be deﬁned in every translation unit in which it is odr-used

You are violating that requirement in the translation unit that includes `main()`. (or remove `inline` from the definition of `init()`)